# Spring + Hibernate: Many-to-Many relationships and web forms

Tags: java, forms, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have been wrestling with how to implement a form that creates many-to-many relations in a web application I am building with Spring 3 and Hibernate 4.  I am trying to build a simple blog tool with a tagging system.  I have created a model `BlogPost` that has a many-to-many relationship with the model `Tags`.  When I create a new `BlogPost` object, the web form input for tags is a single-lined text input.  I'd like to be able to split this text string by whitespace and use it to create `Tag` objects.  Alternatively, when editing an existing `BlogPost`, I'd like to be able to take the `Set` of `Tag` objects associated with the `BlogPost` and convert it to a `String` that is used as the value of the input element.  My problem is in converting between the text input and the referenced set of `Tag` objects using my form.

What is the best practice for binding/fetching/updating many-to-many relationships with web forms?  Is there an easy way to do this that I am unaware of?

**UPDATE**

I decided, as suggested in the answer below, to manually handle the object conversion between the `String` tag values in the form and the `Set<Tag>` object required for the object model.  Here is the final working code:

**editBlogPost.jsp**

```
...
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="tagInput">Tags</label>
    <div class="col-lg-7">
        <input id="tagInput" name="tagString" type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="100" value="${tagString}" />                  
    </div>
    <form:errors path="tags" cssClass="help-inline spring-form-error" element="span" />
</div>
....
```

**BlogController.java**

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("blogPost")
public class BlogController {

    @Autowired
    private BlogService blogService;

    @Autowired 
    private TagService tagService;

    @ModelAttribute("blogPost")
    public BlogPost getBlogPost(){
        return new BlogPost();
    }

    //List Blog Posts
    @RequestMapping(value="/admin/blog", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String blogAdmin(ModelMap map, SessionStatus status){
        status.setComplete();
        List<BlogPost> postList = blogService.getAllBlogPosts();
        map.addAttribute("postList", postList);
        return "admin/blogPostList";
    }

    //Add new blog post
    @RequestMapping(value="/admin/blog/new", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String newPost(ModelMap map){
        BlogPost blogPost = new BlogPost();
        map.addAttribute("blogPost", blogPost);
        return "admin/editBlogPost";
    }

    //Save new post
    @RequestMapping(value="/admin/blog/new", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addPost(@Valid @ModelAttribute BlogPost blogPost, 
            BindingResult result, 
            @RequestParam("tagString") String tagString, 
            Model model, 
            SessionStatus status)
    {
        if (result.hasErrors()){
            return "admin/editBlogPost";
        }
        else {
            Set<Tag> tagSet = new HashSet();

            for (String tag: tagString.split(" ")){

                if (tag.equals("") || tag == null){
                    //pass
                }
                else {
                    //Check to see if the tag exists
                    Tag tagObj = tagService.getTagByName(tag);
                    //If not, add it
                    if (tagObj == null){
                        tagObj = new Tag();
                        tagObj.setTagName(tag);
                        tagService.saveTag(tagObj);
                    }
                    tagSet.add(tagObj);
                }
            }

            blogPost.setPostDate(Calendar.getInstance());
            blogPost.setTags(tagSet);
            blogService.saveBlogPost(blogPost);

            status.setComplete();

            return "redirect:/admin/blog";

        }
    }

    //Edit existing blog post
    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping(value="/admin/blog/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String editPost(ModelMap map, @PathVariable("id") Integer postId){
        BlogPost blogPost = blogService.getBlogPostById(postId);
        map.addAttribute("blogPost", blogPost);
        Hibernate.initialize(blogPost.getTags());
        Set<Tag> tags = blogPost.getTags();
        String tagString = "";
        for (Tag tag: tags){
            tagString = tagString + " " + tag.getTagName();
        }
        tagString = tagString.trim();
        map.addAttribute("tagString", tagString);

        return "admin/editBlogPost";
    }

    //Update post
    @RequestMapping(value="/admin/blog/{id}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String savePostChanges(@Valid @ModelAttribute BlogPost blogPost, BindingResult result, @RequestParam("tagString") String tagString, Model model, SessionStatus status){
        if (result.hasErrors()){
            return "admin/editBlogPost";
        }
        else {
            Set<Tag> tagSet = new HashSet();

            for (String tag: tagString.split(" ")){

                if (tag.equals("") || tag == null){
                    //pass
                }
                else {
                    //Check to see if the tag exists
                    Tag tagObj = tagService.getTagByName(tag);
                    //If not, add it
                    if (tagObj == null){
                        tagObj = new Tag();
                        tagObj.setTagName(tag);
                        tagService.saveTag(tagObj);
                    }
                    tagSet.add(tagObj);
                }
            }
            blogPost.setTags(tagSet);
            blogPost.setPostDate(Calendar.getInstance());
            blogService.updateBlogPost(blogPost);

            status.setComplete();

            return "redirect:/admin/blog";

        }
    }

    //Delete blog post
    @RequestMapping(value="/admin/delete/blog/{id}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String deleteBlogPost(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, SessionStatus status){
        blogService.deleteBlogPost(id);
        status.setComplete();
        return "The item was deleted succesfully";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/admin/blog/cancel", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String cancelBlogEdit(SessionStatus status){
        status.setComplete();
        return "redirect:/admin/blog";
    }

}
```

**BlogPost.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BLOG_POST")
public class BlogPost implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="POST_ID")
    private Integer postId;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=1, max=200)
    @Column(name="TITLE")
    private String title;

    ... 

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="BLOG_POST_TAGS", 
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="POST_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="TAG_ID")})
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<Tag>();

    ...

    public Set<Tag> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(Set<Tag> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

}
```

**Tag.java**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="TAG")
    public class Tag implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name="TAG_ID")
        private Integer tagId;

        @NotNull
        @NotEmpty
        @Size(min=1, max=20)
        @Column(name="TAG_NAME")
        private String tagName;

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="tags")
        private Set<BlogPost> blogPosts = new HashSet<BlogPost>();

        public Integer getTagId() {
            return tagId;
        }

        public void setTagId(Integer tagId) {
            this.tagId = tagId;
        }

        public String getTagName() {
            return tagName;
        }

        public void setTagName(String tag) {
            this.tagName = tag;
        }

        public Set<BlogPost> getBlogPosts() {
            return blogPosts;
        }

        public void setBlogPosts(Set<BlogPost> blogPosts) {
            this.blogPosts = blogPosts;
        }


    }
```

Comment: First, change your method `addPost` to have the `BindingResult` parameter right after your `BlogPost` parameter in the parameter list.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Why does this order make a difference?

Comment: It's a Spring convention. Imagine you had multiple command objects with their corresponding `BindingResult`.

Comment: Next to that to maintain the object also add @ModelAttribute next to @Valid. To implement conversion either construct a `Converter` or a `PropertyEditor` which basically translate from/to a `String`.

Comment: @M.Deinum: If I use a `Converter`, would I be converting b/t `String` and `Set<Tag>`?  Would I then have to include in my converter reference to a service for creating/fetching `Tag` objects?

Comment: If those come from a database you obviously need a way to load/create them.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Yes, I am using MySQL in my case.  My questions is where should this load/creation take place?  Converting a space-delimited `String` to a `Set<Tag>` would imply having to create new `Tag` objects and fetch existing ones.  I have never used many-to-many relationships with Spring/Hibernate before, so I don't know the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose to encode your Tags in a `String` as the transfer data model between client and server you might make your life a little harder if you want to improve your UX later on.

**I would consider having `Set<Tag>` as its own model element and I would do the transformation directly in the front-end using JavaScript on a JSON model.**

Since I would like to have auto completion for my tagging, I would pass all existing Tags as part of the `/admin/blog/new` model with the ability to mark which tags belong to the blog post (e.g. as a `Map<Tag, Boolean>` or two Sets) - most likely with a JSON mapping. I would modify this model using JavaScript in the frontend (perhaps utilizing some jquery plugins that provides some nice autocomplete features) and rely on [default JSON Mapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.html) ([Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)) for the back conversion.

So my model would have at least two elements: the blog post and all the tags (some who are marked as "assigned to this BlogPost". I would use a TagService to ensure existence of all relevant tags, query them with `where name in (<all assigned tag names>)` and set my BlogPost.setTags(assignedTags).

In addition I would want to have some cleanup function to remove unused Tags from the DB. If I would want to make it easier for the server, I would have another model element with the removed removed tags (so I can check whether this was the last BlogPost that used this Tag).

Comment: Interesting idea, I will give it a shot and see if it fits my needs.  Thanks!

Comment: While not what I was initially looking for, I did go in this direction for my solution and am happy with the results.  I'll update my question with my final code.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in your form:

```
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1"
        name="categories"> <label class="form-check-label"
        for="categories"> Cat 1 </label> 

    <input class="form-check-input"
        type="checkbox" value="2" name="categories"> <label
        class="form-check-label" for="categories"> Cat 2 </label>
</div>
```